# Jmeter - Telling http request not to fail

Tags: jmeter

While execution of negative TC (login with Invalid user), i need to login with invalid data, but not get marked the execution as failed in 'View Results Tree', coz this is expected behavior by the system.

[image]

I try changing parameters in .jmx file, but without any result.

[image]

Is this possible to be done, so my 'http request' wont be marked as Failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the failure is being caused by receiving [HTTP Response Code >= 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) you can add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) as a child of the request which is not supposed to fail and tick `Ignore Status` box

[image]

Check out [Response Assertions in JMeter 3.2 - New and Improved](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) article for more information on defining custom pass/fail criteria with Response Assertion

If your request fails for any other reason - please clarify it so we could come up with the optimal solution. Be aware that you can mark the request as passed using [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) and the following Groovy code:

```
prev.setSuccessful(true)
```

Comment: That's was what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use a single Response Assertion with only 'ignore status' option checked.

See below screenshot

[image]

Go through the below link for more details on this.

https://funwithjmeter.blogspot.com/2018/12/jmeter-pass-http-failed-request.html